# "Item Cannot Be Found In The Collection" when calling stored procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here is my proc:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_user]
        @username varchar(50)
     AS
     BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = @username)
            SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = @username
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (@username)
                SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = @username
            END
     END
```

Here is my VBA

```
Public userid As Integer
    Public dbconn As ADODB.Connection

Public Function Startup()
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim param As New ADODB.Parameter

    Set dbconn = New ADODB.Connection
    dbconn.ConnectionString = "[redacted]"
    dbconn.Open dbconn.ConnectionString

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "insert_user"

    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Environ("UserDomain") & "dddddddd\" & Environ("Username"))
    cmd.Parameters.Append param

    rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rs.Open cmd

    MsgBox (rs("userid"))
End Function
```

It fails whenever the proc is adding a new user but works fine when an existing user returns. Any idea why it's not returning any records when I do an insert?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help you: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62936

So, actually, it is about adding one line to your stored procedure:

```
...
SET NOCOUNT ON
...
```